# I accidentally told someone there my idol a year ago on message but I didn't mean it as in worship I meant it as in I want to be like him. What to do?

Tags: allah, sin, shirk, forgiveness

A year ago, I messaged someone I knew and told them "your not gonna see this but your my idol. I wanna say thanks for making me smile." I didn't mean it as in worship, I mean it in someone I looked up to. I am worried that since I called him that is is "shirk" and I don't want to go to hell and I don't know what to do because I love Allah SWT and I don't want to get punished for saying something I didn't mean and my iman was not strong at the time. Please give me advice.

Comment: the most egregious transgression here is saying "your" instead of "you're" ;)

Comment: Do not fret over homonyms. None would misinterpret your intentions.

Answer (score -1):

I personally myself stay away from things which can have meaning in the category of Shirk e.g Nike shoes or Mazda etc. I too searched about the meaning of Idol on the internet it can have both meanings based on what you are referring too. But still avoiding using these kind of words would be preferable. Allah knows the best
Jazakallah